# Force TextField to select full text on focus

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'd like to get a TextField to select the whole text currently in the field whenever I click/tap/focus on the field. I've done this myself in other React apps with an `onFocus` handler that does an `event.target.select()`, but this approach does not seem to work with Material-UI. With Material-UI TextFields I can see the selection briefly cover the full text, then it returns to just a cursor blinking at the end of the text.

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: Please include the code that you used in your attempt.

Comment: Turns out that this is not a Material-UI issue at all. Thanks, Ryan, for pushing me a bit. Here is another React App without any Material components exhibiting the same behavior on Safari. Interesting to note that when I create a similar static page without any React at all, this static app works just fine, even in Safari. So I think the problem is with React and Safari (and Mobile Safari, unfortunately), not with Material-UI at all.

Comment: FYI, I just asked this question with better code examples and a ReactJS tag at https://stackoverflow.com/q/54229359/383737.

Comment: This got a nice answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54229871/383737.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This works fine for me using the following code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

function App() {
  return (
    <TextField
      defaultValue="test"
      onFocus={event => {
        event.target.select();
      }}
    />
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit rj48vp8rlm]

If this does not help with your problem, please share the code that reproduces your issue.

Comment: Thank you for this example, oddly enough it behaved just the same as my own (very similar) code. Then I thought to test on another browser. This code works as you would expect on Chrome but does not work properly on Safari (both up-to-date on macOS). I will have to test this in plain Javascript to see if the problem is deeper.

Comment: I had only tried it on Chrome. I’ll look into this more tomorrow on other browsers if I have time.